# How do I store a boolean value that takes in yes or no without quotes?

Tags: sql, database

For my assignment I need help storing a boolean value that can hold yes or no. The column name is Required and the column attributes I received are ***Boolean value (1/0 or T/F) , Default value: NULL***

I listed the sample data to be used bellow. The yes/no has to be stored without quotes somehow. Thank you

```
INSERT INTO CIS_Courses
VALUES ("CIS 105", "Computer Applications and Information Technology", null, Yes);
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server ? Please dont tag all the RDBMS. I have remove the RDBMS tags. Edit the question to tag with the specific RDBMS you are using.

Comment: I'd guess MySQL. (Based on those double quoted string literals...)

Comment: I don't understand the question. `Yes` is no value. The string `'Yes'` would be. But if your DBMS supports boolean columns, you would rather use this and store `true` or `false`. E.g. `INSERT INTO CIS_Courses (course_number, title, starting_date, confirmed) VALUES ('CIS 105', 'Computer Applications and Information Technology', null, true);`

Comment: On a sidenote: You should not use double quotes for string literals. The delimiter for string literals is the single quote. The double quote, according to the SQL standard, is for names (table names, column names, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

boolean data type is not available in sql server
you can use BIT datatype to represent boolean data. 
A BIT field's value is either 1,0 or null

It also use the strings 'true' and 'false' in place of 1 or 0, like so-

```
declare @a bit = 'false'
print @a                   --output 0

declare @b bit = 'true'
print @b                   -- output 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use tinyint(1) as boolean type value. Your table column would look like:

```
ColumnName tinyint(1) not null default 0
```

So when you don't insert a value, it will automatically be 0, or you can insert a 0 or 1.

I hope that this will help you

Comment: Which DBMS are you referring to? Doesn't your DBMS support a boolean datatype or is there anything that speaks against using it?

Comment: `tinyint` is universal, not all SQL servers support boolean.

Comment: Well, tinyint is not universal, but yes, many support it and the others support some numeric datatype, too. So your argument is that `WHERE NOT available` or even `HAVING EVERY(available)` would only run in certain DBMS that support a boolean datatype (and such function), while `WHERE available = 0` or `HAVING MIN(available) = 1` would work in all? So you are striving to have your database as portable as possible? That's a fair enough reason.

Comment: I think it will work out for that case, yes. Since it isn't declared which type of database he's using.